# jQuery: Select all children of the last th

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I need to select all children of the last th table element.

I already tried something like this:

```
th:last-children
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Do you mean instead to select all the TDs elements of the last table's column?

Answer (score 1):

This line should works :

```
$('th:last').children();
```

Answer (score 0):

`th:last-children` will select th which are last child in their container. you need to use `th:last` to target last th element along with `.children()` to get its immediate child elements:

```
$('th:last').children();
```

or

```
$('th:last > *');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        jQuery( "table th:last-child" ).last().css( "color", "red" );
        alert(jQuery( "table th:last-child" ).last().html());
        jQuery("th:last-child").css('background','yellow');

    })
    </script>
```